# To close session in wso2 using dblookup mediator

Tags: wso2

I have one question: how can I close the database connection in wso2 manually when using dblookup mediator?
I saw the dblookup mediator code on github [here] (https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/db/DBLookupMediator.java). I saw that the dblookup mediator code uses the "finally" part of the code where all connections are closed, BUT when I check all active sessions to the database, I see that the connections are still open.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `DblookUp Mediator` maintains a connection pool. Hence closing the connection may return it back to the pool. If you want to reduce the size of the pool probably you can try tuning the connection pool settings. For example this property `maxactive` will set max active connections. Take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/dBLookup-Mediator/) document.

Also, AFAIK there is no way to manually flush the connections.